# Sphinx - Search phrase in comma separated string

Tags: php, sphinx

In `Sphinx`, I want to search for a phrase in comma separated string.

For example, the comma separated string is `Very Expensive,Luxury,Romance,Trendy`.

The phrase `"Expensive"` should not match this record, but the phrase `"Very Expensive"` should be matched.

Tried setting [Phrase Boundary](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/2.0.5/conf-phrase-boundary.html) option in sphinx configuration file and rotated the indexer again, but there is no change in the output.

```
phrase_boundary                 =  U+002C # comma
phrase_boundary_step            =  100
```

I'm using `Sphinx 2.0.5` with `PHP` as scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solve this, (indexing Tags) is to use a specific seperator. Eg index it as

```
_SEP_ Very Expensive _SEP_ Luxury _SEP_ Romance _SEP_ Trendy _SEP_
```

Now can run a query `"_SEP_ Very Expensive _SEP_"` (with the quotes) and it will match nice, however a query `"_SEP_ Expensive _SEP_"` will NOT match :)

---

(can build this dynamically in `sql_query`, eg

```
... , CONCAT('_SEP_ ',REPLACE(labels,',',' _SEP_ '),' _SEP_') AS labels, ...
```

(at least for a mysql data source)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `field-start` and `field-end` modifiers using the [Extended query syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax). In this case you would need to break your comma separated strings ("Very Expensive", "Luxury" etc) into the separate fields while indexing.

Your search queries then would look like these:

`^Very Expensive$` - matches the entire field

`^Expensive$` - does not match the entire field